# How to obtain all the links in a domain using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to use Python to obtain all the links in a domain given the 'root' URL (in a list). Suppose given a URL http://www.example.com this should return all the links on this page of the same domain as the root URL, then recurse on each of these links visiting them and extracting all the links of the same domain and so on. What I mean by same domain is if given http://www.example.com the only links I want back are http://www.example.com/something, http://www.example.com/somethingelse ... Anything external such as http://www.otherwebsite.com should be discarded. How can I do this using Python?

EDIT: I made an attempt using lxml. I don't think this works fully, and I am not sure how to take into account links to already processed pages (causing infinite loop).

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

#given a url returns list of all sublinks within the same domain
def getLinks(url):
        urlList = []
        urlList.append(url)
        sublinks = getSubLinks(url)
        for link in sublinks:
                absolute = url+'/'+link
                urlList.extend(getLinks(absolute))
         return urlList

#determine whether two links are within the same domain
def sameDomain(url, dom):
    return url.startswith(dom)

#get tree of sublinks in same domain, url is root
def getSubLinks(url):
    sublinks = []
    connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
    dom = lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
    for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
                if not (link.startswith('#') or link.startswith('http') or link.startswith('mailto:')):
                        sublinks.append(link)
    return sublinks
```

~

Comment: From the question tags it seems that you already know what to use. Perhaps you could show what you have tried, otherwise I think the question is too general. There are web scraping frameworks around such as [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) that might help you.

Comment: This question is difficult in that, some links in the page aren't prefixed by protocol and provide local path. ".." is a valid URL. What do you want to follow and not to ?

Comment: I simply want to follow anything which is prefixed by the root URL. However, some relative links are not prefixed by the root URL but would be valid if i prepended the root URL to them. I also want these.

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import requests
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

def get_soup(link):
    """
    Return the BeautifulSoup object for input link
    """
    request_object = requests.get(link, auth=('user', 'pass'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_object.content)
    return soup

def get_status_code(link):
    """
    Return the error code for any url
    param: link
    """
    try:
        error_code = requests.get(link).status_code
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        error_code = 
    return error_code

def find_internal_urls(lufthansa_url, depth=0, max_depth=2):
    all_urls_info = []
    status_dict = {}
    soup = get_soup(lufthansa_url)
    a_tags = soup.findAll("a", href=True)

    if depth > max_depth:
        return {}
    else:
        for a_tag in a_tags:
            if "http" not in a_tag["href"] and "/" in a_tag["href"]:
                url = "http://www.lufthansa.com" + a_tag['href']
            elif "http" in a_tag["href"]:
                url = a_tag["href"]
            else:
                continue
            status_dict["url"] = url
            status_dict["status_code"] = get_status_code(url)
            status_dict["timestamp"] = datetime.now()
            status_dict["depth"] = depth + 1
            all_urls_info.append(status_dict)
    return all_urls_info
if __name__ == "__main__":
    depth = 2 # suppose 
    all_page_urls = find_internal_urls("someurl", 2, 2)
    if depth > 1:
        for status_dict in all_page_urls:
            find_internal_urls(status_dict['url'])
```

The above snippet contains necessary modules for scrapping urls from lufthansa arlines website. The only thing additional here is you can specify depth to which you want to scrape recursively.

Comment: This makes sense, but how does this recurse? It seems to find only the links for the first 'level'.

Comment: You add the depth and it will search to that much depth.

Comment: But where is find_internal_urls actually called by itself and thereby recursing on links?

Comment: I have provided modules, you can the function wherever you want as per your need!

Comment: I don't think this will work.  You're mutating all_page_urls in find_internal_urls.  So in the main method you're changing what you're iterating over within the loop, which python views as a party foul.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done, only following full urls like http://domain[xxx]. Quick but a bit dirty.

```
import requests
import re

domain = u"stackoverflow.com"
http_re = re.compile(u"(http:\/\/" + domain + "[\/\w \.-]*\/?)")

visited = set([])
def visit (url):
    visited.add (url)
    extracted_body = requests.get (url).text
    matches = re.findall (http_re, extracted_body)
    for match in matches:
        if match not in visited :
            visit (match)

visit(u"http://" + domain)    
print (visited)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in the code of @namita . I modify it and it works well now.

```
import sys
import requests
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime


def get_soup(link):
    """
    Return the BeautifulSoup object for input link
    """
    request_object = requests.get(link, auth=('user', 'pass'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_object.content, "lxml")
    return soup

def get_status_code(link):
    """
    Return the error code for any url
    param: link
    """
    try:
        error_code = requests.get(link).status_code
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        error_code = -1
    return error_code

def find_internal_urls(main_url, depth=0, max_depth=2):
    all_urls_info = []

    soup = get_soup(main_url)
    a_tags = soup.findAll("a", href=True)

    if main_url.endswith("/"):
        domain = main_url
    else:
        domain = "/".join(main_url.split("/")[:-1])
    print(domain)
    if depth > max_depth:
        return {}
    else:
        for a_tag in a_tags:
            if "http://" not in a_tag["href"] and "https://" not in a_tag["href"] and "/" in a_tag["href"]:
                url = domain + a_tag['href']
            elif "http://" in a_tag["href"] or "https://" in a_tag["href"]:
                url = a_tag["href"]
            else:
                continue
            # print(url)

            status_dict = {}
            status_dict["url"] = url
            status_dict["status_code"] = get_status_code(url)
            status_dict["timestamp"] = datetime.now()
            status_dict["depth"] = depth + 1
            all_urls_info.append(status_dict)
    return all_urls_info


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = # your domain here
    depth = 1
    all_page_urls = find_internal_urls(url, 0, 2)
    # print("\n\n",all_page_urls)
    if depth > 1:
        for status_dict in all_page_urls:
            find_internal_urls(status_dict['url'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**The code worked, but I don't know if it's 100% correct**
**it is extracting all the internal urls in the website**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup(link):
    """
    Return the BeautifulSoup object for input link
    """
    request_object = requests.get(link, auth=('user', 'pass'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_object.content, "lxml")
    return soup

visited = set([])
def visit (url,domain):
    visited.add (url)
    soup = get_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.findAll("a", href=True)
    for a_tag in a_tags:
        if "http://" not in a_tag["href"] and "https://" not in a_tag["href"] and "/" in a_tag["href"]:
            url = domain + a_tag['href']
        elif "http://" in a_tag["href"] or "https://" in a_tag["href"]:
            url = a_tag["href"]
        else:
            continue
        if url not in visited and domain in url:
            # print(url)
            visit (url,domain)

url=input("Url: ")
domain=input("domain: ")
visit(u"" + url,domain)
print (visited)
```

Answer (score -1):

From the tags of your question, I assume you are using Beautiful Soup.
At first, you obviously need to download the webpage, for example with urllib.request. After you did that and have the contents in a string, you pass it to Beautiful Soup. After that, you can find all links with soup.find_all('a'), assuming soup is your beautiful soup object. After that, you simply need to check the hrefs:

The most simple version would be to just check if "http://www.example.com" is in the href, but that won't catch relative links. I guess some wild regular expression would do (find everything with "www.example.com" or starting with "/" or starting with "?" (php)), or you might look for everything that contains a www, but is not www.example.com and discard it, etc. The correct strategy might be depending on the website you are scraping, and it's coding style.

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expression to filter out such links

eg

```
<a\shref\=\"(http\:\/\/example\.com[^\"]*)\"
```

Take the above regex as reference and start writing script based on that.